# quarkus with resteasy-reactive doesn't rebalance the load

Tags: configuration, quarkus

I'm using quarkus-restasy-reactive and my application (8 pods/k8s) receives a lot of GET requests(1000/s) from other application (20 machines).
I saw that the application client doesn't change the port or the machine regardless of the number of request, probably reusing the same socket.
So It doesn't rebalance the load when I deploy my application.
Is that a configuration from quarkus? or the client? Below is some of the config I set in my application.

```
quarkus.vertx.prefer-native-transport=true
quarkus.http.so-reuse-port=true
quarkus.http.tcp-quick-ack=true
quarkus.http.tcp-cork=true
quarkus.http.tcp-fast-open=true
```

Comment: How is the application being called by the other applications?

Comment: @geoand the other applications are logstashs with http plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html).

Comment: Okay. What URL are they using to hit the application?

Comment: it's a intern url without https like <http://my-internal-domain.intranet/api/186.251.182.74>

Comment: My point is that if you are not using a Kubernetes `Service`, then your client won't get load balanced

Comment: ah, sorry, I'm using k8s service, the domain points to the address of Kubernetes service